# OpenGL ES is crashing when rendering code is loaded while rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have a tree structure of Renderers. If I load them up **before rendering** everything works fine, but if I load them **while rendering** I get a memory dump.

```
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  r0 00000000  r1 4bf22eb0  r2 00000010  r3 00000004
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  r4 0023d2e8  r5 0023e154  r6 00000000  r7 00000004
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  r8 00000010  r9 00000010  10 00000000  fp 00000001
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  ip 00000001  sp 4b7bdaa8  lr 81b06b70  pc 81b30dc0  cpsr 80000010
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d0  6472656767756265  d1  0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d2  000000640024c100  d3  0000000044936800
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d6  000000000012eca8  d7  0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d16 c1d0a059b6bb9581  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d18 41c9bc2c66800000  d19 3fe000000025a36b
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
02-07 17:50:00.721: INFO/DEBUG(2355):  scr 20000012
02-07 17:50:00.815: INFO/DEBUG(2355):          #00  pc 00030dc0  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:50:00.823: INFO/DEBUG(2355):          #01  lr 81b06b70  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:50:00.823: INFO/DEBUG(2355): code around pc:
02-07 17:50:00.823: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b30da0 e781410c e28cc001 e15c0003 3afffffa 
02-07 17:50:00.823: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b30db0 e8bd8010 e92d4010 e3a0c000 ea000004 
02-07 17:50:00.823: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b30dc0 e5904000 e5014008 e5904004 e0800002 
02-07 17:50:00.827: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b30dd0 e5014004 e15c0003 e2811008 e28cc001 
02-07 17:50:00.831: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b30de0 3afffff6 e8bd8010 e92d4010 e3a0c000 
02-07 17:50:00.831: INFO/DEBUG(2355): code around lr:
02-07 17:50:00.835: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b06b50 e3530000 1a000005 e59c0028 e1a03007 
02-07 17:50:00.835: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b06b60 e59c102c e59c2024 e1a0e00f e59cf034 
02-07 17:50:00.838: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b06b70 e2866001 e2855004 e5942ec0 e3a03001 
02-07 17:50:00.838: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b06b80 e1560002 3affffeb e088800a e2840d77 
02-07 17:50:00.838: INFO/DEBUG(2355): 81b06b90 e2888003 e280000c e1a02003 e0278799 
02-07 17:50:00.838: INFO/DEBUG(2355): stack:
02-07 17:50:00.838: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda68  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.842: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda6c  afd0bfc9  /system/lib/libc.so
02-07 17:50:00.842: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda70  00000000  
02-07 17:50:00.846: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda74  00000001  
02-07 17:50:00.846: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda78  00000003  
02-07 17:50:00.846: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda7c  00000001  
02-07 17:50:00.850: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda80  00000000  
02-07 17:50:00.854: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda84  00000000  
02-07 17:50:00.854: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda88  000e44f0  [heap]
02-07 17:50:00.858: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda8c  0023d2e8  [heap]
02-07 17:50:00.858: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda90  0023e154  [heap]
02-07 17:50:00.858: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda94  00000000  
02-07 17:50:00.862: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda98  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.862: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bda9c  00000010  
02-07 17:50:00.862: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdaa0  df002777  
02-07 17:50:00.866: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdaa4  e3a070ad  
02-07 17:50:00.866: INFO/DEBUG(2355): #00 4b7bdaa8  0023d2e8  [heap]
02-07 17:50:00.866: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdaac  81b06b70  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:50:00.866: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdab0  0023d2e8  [heap]
02-07 17:50:00.866: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdab4  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.870: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdab8  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.870: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdabc  00000000  
02-07 17:50:00.874: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdac0  00000005  
02-07 17:50:00.874: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdac4  00000001  
02-07 17:50:00.874: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdac8  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.874: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdacc  81b08510  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:50:00.874: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdad0  0023d2e8  [heap]
02-07 17:50:00.874: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdad4  81b6a5fc  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:50:00.878: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdad8  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.878: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdadc  00000000  
02-07 17:50:00.878: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdae0  00000005  
02-07 17:50:00.878: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdae4  81b09954  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:50:00.878: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdae8  00000004  
02-07 17:50:00.881: INFO/DEBUG(2355):     4b7bdaec  00000000
```

All the renderer does is:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mArraybuffer);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TextureMap), NULL);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TextureMap), (void *)offsetof(TextureMap, coord));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, mSize);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

and I know it crashes on `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`. What I want to know is why is it crashing, or at least a reason why I shouldn't be doing what I'm doing?

**EDIT:** I have designed it to load the renderer with the code above when the screen is tapped. It generates an array buffer and assigns the array accordingly. I then add the renderer to the renderer tree, but when it first renders it crashes and get the above memory dump.

```
        GLuint arraybuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &arraybuffer);

        TextureMap data[] = {
                {{-69.573, 39.74}, {325.0/512.0, 279.75/512.0}},
                {{-69.573, 83.24}, {325.0/512.0, 323.25/512.0}},
                {{71.571, 39.74}, {466.45/512.0, 279.75/512.0}},
                {{71.571, 83.24}, {466.45/512.0, 323.25/512.0}},
        };

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, arraybuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TextureMap) * 4, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        TextureMapBufferRenderer *renderer = new TextureMapBufferRenderer(arraybuffer); //generates a renderer for array buffer
        renderer->load();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        mManager->renderer()->addChildRenderer(renderer);
```

The above code is when it executed on tap. If I put the same code at the beginning it will work.

Comment: This is hard to say without seeing the surrounding code. Could you post a bit more about how this is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might explain my issue

[Can't call glGenTextures on multithreaded android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527878/cant-call-glgentextures-on-multithreaded-android-app)

**Update:**
It seems to be the issue, moving the code so that it loads on Render thread it works, but not I get `dequeuing buffer error (Unknown error: -75)`. All I know is it something to do with OpenGL ES context.

**Update #2:**
Turns out this was the problem. I needed to load everything at the beginning, before rendering has started. It might be possible to do it dynamically by stopping the thread and then loading what you want, but I would say it's easier to just load everything up from the beginning.