# EAGLSharegroup like functionality for cross platform developement in c++ openGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, cross-platform, cocos2d-x, gpuimage

I am trying to use a c++ port of the [GPUImage](https://github.com/Dexterp37/GPUImage) library in a cross-platform cocos2d-x game. Both GPUImage and cocos2d-x create their own OpenGL context to perform operations on the GPU, and this causes problems in the application. For the original GPUImage library created for iOS, the author has suggested using 'sharegroup' to share the contexts between GPUImage and cocos2d [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160995/cocos2d-opengl-error-0x0502-in-eaglview-swapbuffers). Use of the 'sharegroup' is also given in Apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html) . Since, I want to make a cross-platform game (for android and iOS) I was looking for the same functionality on other platforms such as Android? Is it possible to implement this on cross-platform?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it like suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892531/369009

> Android supplies EGL, which supports the common concept of an OpenGL
>   share group (although implicitly; you supply an existing context that
>   you want a new context to be in a common group with via the third
>   argument to eglCreateContext). If two contexts are in a share group
>   then each of them has an independent state and is safe to call from
>   only one thread but named objects such as textures or vertex buffer
>   objects are available to each of them. So using share groups you can
>   perform OpenGL actions on multiple threads simultaneously so as to be
>   able to combine the results on a single thread.

Would this work? I guess it would be pretty cross platform (wherever EGL is supported), however you would have to synchronize access to the shared objects (textures, ...) somehow.