# Problems changing the texture of a polygon in a thread.... white textures

Tags: android, opengl-es

In some point of my app i need to changue the texture of a polygon.

For that, i must load a bitmap from assets folder and then i pass the bitmap to a "loadBitmap" method of my polygon that changes the texture.

It is working fine, but i need to move the code into a thread, because the loading time of the bitmap it's frozing my opengl polygon when it's loading the bitmap from assets folder.

Because that i implemented a thread that it is called to change the texture, but something is going wrong because my texture is empty (white) when i use the thread, but it works if i dont use the thread, this is my thread code:

```
public class addNextPage extends Thread
{
    GL10 gl;
    public addNextPage(GL10 gl) {
        super();
        this.gl = gl;
    }       
    public void run() 
    {
        super.run();

        Bitmap bm=loadImage(pages.get(0));
        auxSquare.loadBitmap(context, gl, bm);  
        squares.set(3,auxSquare);

        currentPage+=1;                 
        //vuelvo a recolocar los squares
        int posCont=-2; //el primer polígono está a la izquierda, no se ve.
        for (int i=0;i<squares.size();i++){
            if (squares.get(i)!=null)
                squares.get(i).setPosition(posCont,0);
            posCont+=2;
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call super? Maybe this will work:

```
public class addNextPage extends Thread {
GL10 gl;
public addNextPage(GL10 gl) {
    this.gl = gl;
}       
public void run() 
{

    Bitmap bm=loadImage(pages.get(0));
    auxSquare.loadBitmap(context, gl, bm);  
    squares.set(3,auxSquare);

    currentPage+=1;                 
    //vuelvo a recolocar los squares
    int posCont=-2; //el primer polígono está a la izquierda, no se ve.
    for (int i=0;i<squares.size();i++){
        if (squares.get(i)!=null)
            squares.get(i).setPosition(posCont,0);
        posCont+=2;
    }           
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call `texImage2D`? It must be called on the main rendering thread. Or, create a second OpenGL context for your background thread.

I described a java-only solution for uploading textures on a separate thread as an answer to another question: [Threading textures load process for android opengl game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318311/threading-textures-load-process-for-android-opengl-game/19740938#19740938)