# OpenGL ES Android Loading Screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm creating an OpenGL-based 2D game. I want to create a loading screen to load my assets. I want to draw something to show the user that something is loading. But I learned that I can't use a separate thread like asynctask to load my textures. So I'm stuck there. How can I create a loading screen to load my assets?

Comment: This is off topic. But I wonder why more devices don't have neat hardware-accelerated loading or splash screens. I bet if certain Android devices had seriously kick ass 3D loading screens more people would buy those particular devices. To address your question: the loading screen isn't what's loading your assets. It's there to provide feedback to the user. Have you even gotten the "loading assets" part of your program working yet?

Comment: Yes normally my game is running but after i want to create a loading screen i started to use asynctask to load my assets.Because of opengl's context problem i loaded my textures but textures needs to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "load". The loading is a two-step process:

1. Load the image into (main) memory. This can be done from any thread.
2. Create the texture by loading the image into video memory. This has to be done from the GL thread.

The texture creation a la `glTexImage2d` can slow things down a bit temporarily in terms of FPS, but this isn't a problem normally, especially when you're showing a (static) loading screen.

So in principle you could do all of the loading on the GL thread, if your splash screen is static (i.e. nothing moves and hence FPS doesn't matter):

1. Load the splash screen assets into memory
2. Create the splash screen texture & draw splash screen
3. Load the game assets into memory
4. Create the game screen textures & draw game screen

If your splash screen is dynamic however, you will want to do 3. on a separate loading thread, and once that is done, create the game textures on the GL thread. This requires signalling from the loading thread to the GL thread that the loading of the assets is ready for texture creation.

Comment: "This requires signalling from the loading thread to the GL thread that the loading of the assets is ready for texture creation." and yes i'm asking how to signal from seperate thread to gl thread?

Comment: This can be done in a variety of ways (any cross-thread communication technique), and follows the same paradigm as handling e.g. a user input from the UI thread as illustrated on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html. You could also simply check a isBitmapReady flag in the onDrawFrame() method, which you set to true when your loading thread has finished, and subsequently fire off your texture creation.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use something like the accepted answer for [Threading textures load process for android opengl game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318311/threading-textures-load-process-for-android-opengl-game)

I.e. have a separate thread load a texture into memory, then the main thread does the glTexImage2d call for that texture while the other thread starts loading another texture, and so on. The main thread could also update a progress meter on screen after each glTexImage2d call. The progress reports would be a bit crude, but I don't know how precise you need them to be.