# How to load OpenGL ES textures with almost no visible FPS drop?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have around 2 GiB of textures (all are 256x256 tiles) in uncompressed RGBA 8888 format (the RGB 565 texture format is not an option, because there are lots smooth gradients and shades of gray, which have green tint with 565 format). So I load them on demand, when they should become visible and delete the old ones. The problem is, that there is an annoying FPS drop when I upload them OpenGL. Currently using OpenGL ES 1.1.

I decode the textures in a separate thread (i.e. BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)) and then send the Bitmap to GL thread and upload it as a texture. When this happens the GL thread is *sometimes* slowed-down a bit for this upload. I measured the texture upload time and mostly it varys from 1-8ms, in average it is ~2ms. But from time-to-time it is 40-70ms. What can cause this drop?

I also generate mipmaps on the GPU (disabling mipmaps does not affect this behaviour) and here are all the texture parameters:

```
GLES11.glTexParameterf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
GLES11.glTexParameterf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES11.GL_LINEAR);
GLES11.glTexParameterf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES11.glTexParameterf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES11.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES11.glTexParameterf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES11.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GLES11.GL_TRUE);
GLES11.glTexEnvx(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GLES11.GL_MODULATE);

GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES11.GL_RGBA, bmp, 0);
```

How can I do this better? E.g. how are Open GL video players done, when they need to load and display many frames per second? Or current web browser which render pages as tiles? Is EGL_image a good option worth looking at? Will be OpenGL ES 2.0 different?

**EDIT:**
The slow down of loading was because of GC-ing on the GL thread.

Comment: I think you may have to venture into opengles 2.0 for this. The fact that you are doing your texture upload on your gl thread would cause an fps drop since it will block. if you can upload your texture on a separate thread completely and then pass the texture handle to ur gl thread, that may fix your problem. also have a look at SurfaceTextures

Comment: @Fonix I am not aware of that OpenGL ES 2.0 allows uploading textures from a different thread, are you sure about this?

Comment: if you take a look at the video playback example at the bottom of this page https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk it will show you how it does texture loading for the video frames on one thread (check the videoPlayerHelper class), and does the update loop on another. They use a SurfaceTexture, but I dont think its necessary

Comment: @Fonix I am browsing that source code but cannot find calls to "glTexImage" except in VideoPlayback.cpp. There is a "texImage" call in updateVideoData() (VideoPlayerHelper.java) but it is a SurfaceTexture call and I cannot see what it does. I also see no code indicating threads in the VideoPlayerHelper class. It looks like the MediaPlayer updates the texture on its own. Can you point out where do they call a "glTexImage" method on a different thread than the GL one?

Comment: my mistake actually, the surface texture is used for rendering video to a texture instead of a view, so that option wont be viable for you anyway. Im actually working on a similar problem to you at the moment, except on iOS. if i get my textures loading on a separate thread ill report back, but it might be a few days till i get it working. Im trying to render a webpage to a quad, and it will have to update the texture in the background for displaying. so will see what happens

Comment: it looks like you need to have 2 opengl contexts to be able to do this, one for doing the rendering, while the other can do the loading of the texture, otherwise it will bottle neck the rendering. in iOS there is a thing called a sharegroup that lets you share resources between contexts ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html ) you will have to see what the android equivalent is

Comment: @Fonix having and sharing OpenGL contexts on Android is not very  reliable, nor is the EGL_image (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760675). So a solution, which will work on many devices is not worth implementing in my case :( if it was just EGL_image, then I would go for it, but in current state, I will just suffer the slow down. Thanks

Comment: How do you know the slow down is caused by GC on the GL thread?

Comment: @howerknea this was a long time ago but I think that the slow down was *only* when the GL thread was GC-ing. And when a thread is making a GC then it pauses all other activities on that thread thus the delay of the texture upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it, but not with native code, nor with EGL_image, but thanks to this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8). Fortunatelly I had almost all textures in 256x256 and I am targeting Android 3.2 and newer, so for this scenario there is an easy solution:

[BitmapOptions.inBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap) which will reuse one `Bitmap` for every new tile, so no more furios GC-ing. I had to enlarge the few bitmaps that where smaller than 256x256.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure the GC does not kick in, you could do all the bitmap generation and texture upload on a separate thread as described in my answer to a similar question: [Threading textures load process for android opengl game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318311/threading-textures-load-process-for-android-opengl-game/19740938#19740938)

This would prevent you from small frame drops when the upload itself takes to long.

Comment: I used OpenGL share groups on PCs ages ago, but at the time I asked this question (almost year ago) I read about problems with creating multiple OpenGL contexts in an Android app. I will definitely try it as my new projects will target Jelly Bean and up. Thank you.