# How to keep OpenGL textures after activity is paused in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

At this moment I am reloading the textures every time the app is resumed, however this is taking too long. Every time the game is resumed the player has to wait about 5 seconds for the textures to reload. Is there a way to keep the textures saved so that I won't need to reload them every time the game is resumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you can manage that using the visibility of the view:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onPause();
    ...
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && view.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    ...
}
```

i also found some discussion that can be useful for you :

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/workaround-to-losing-the-opengl-context-when-android-pauses

[Threading textures load process for android opengl game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318311/threading-textures-load-process-for-android-opengl-game)

Hope it will be useful... Good luck