# C# OpenTK load texture wrong in a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, opengl, opentk

*sorry for my bad english*
I've a form OpenTK, normally the event OnLoad is called only once for load all the textures but if i create a thread async in the event with a infinite loop and i put the same code my variable is assigned like the previous but when i draw my Quad appair only the quad white without texture.

Why i want make an infinite loop? I've another form who start the opentk form and i want from the main form add things to the opentk (like a GameEngine)

1)OnLoad loop with new thread

`loadTexture = new Thread(() =>
{

      while (true)
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < toLoad.Count; i++)
           {
                 Contents.LoadTexture(toLoad[i]);
                 loaded.Add(toLoad[i]);
                 toLoad.RemoveAt(i);
           }
           Thread.Sleep(300);
       }
}`

2)OnLoad normal (definite element, i dont need)

```
texture1 = Contents.LoadTexture("Texture1.jpg");
```

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading textures load process for android opengl game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318311/threading-textures-load-process-for-android-opengl-game)

Comment: I've voted to close this, I can't find an exactly identical question, but the concept is the same between languages. OpenGL was not designed with multi-threading in mind. There are plenty of resources out there for creating a context that allows you to do this. Here is one example: http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2011/05/26/multi-thread-opengl-texture-loading/

Comment: Without a setup like that (and even with it, it's not perfectly stable) OpenGL is designed to be handled from only one thread. That thread should have a main loop (renders at the refresh rate of the monitor by default).

The best setup IMO is to have your one graphics thread and all of your other forms will communicate with that thread to let it know what to do with OpenGL.

If you don't mind being on the bleeding edge, Vulkan will let you do things from multiple threads.

Comment: And, its possible call OnLoad more times?

Comment: I don't believe so, though there should be no reason to. If you want to have something happen multiple times after initialization, set some condition for it and have it happen in UpdateFrame.

Comment: ok fixed was my fault, i changed something in the draw method..