# OpenGLES preloading textures in other thread

Tags: java, c++, android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I NEED to preload some textures in the non-main-thread of an OpenGLES application. I read this: [Can't call glGenTextures on multithreaded android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527878/cant-call-glgentextures-on-multithreaded-android-app) but its more the Java version of what I need. How do I tell my loading Thread to upload/create a texture into the main loop? I read something about creating a context and share with the main context somehow. How?

Comment: I described a java-only solution for uploading textures on a separate thread as an answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318311/threading-textures-load-process-for-android-opengl-game/19740938#19740938

Answer (score 3):

There are two steps to get textures from resources/disk to rendering in GL, and they can be separated to allow most of the loading and computational work on a worker thread.

The first step is the actual creation of a Bitmap at the Java level, which will use something like BitmapFactory.decodeResouce().  This part can be done on any thread you like, and when you're done loading you throw that bitmap into an ArrayList or queue or whatever.  Make sure you surround the access of the list with a synchronized block.

The second step is to call glGenTextures, which has to be done in the GL thread.  So at the beginning of your drawFrame() method, check the size of that ArrayList you're saving bitmaps to, and if the size is bigger than 0, make some calls to glGenTexures and remove and recycyle the bitmaps from the array.

Comment: He should rather load textures in `surfaceCreated()` than in `drawFrame()`.

Comment: @Pompe de velo - If you've got a lot of loading to do, you will likely want to show some kind of loading / progress indicator to the user and load your textures over multiple drawFrame() calls.  Doing all your loading in surfaceCreated, which might take several seconds or more, could give the perception that your app has hung due to the unresponsive display/UI, and even result in an ANR.

Comment: Not correct. ANR happens if you are delaying the UI thread, not the rendering thread. However, loading in `surfaceCreated()` makes much more sense since that is the place to do one time initialization.

Comment: Oooook, so no ANR.  But if you're going to be loading more than a trivial set of images, it's more user-friendly to display a progress indicator and do the heavy work across multiple calls to drawFrame().  This approach is also more robust, since you'd be able to load images later without depending on future calls to surfaceCreated().

Comment: I do not agree with you, but I'm sure you have your reasons while I have mine. :-) Have a nice day!

Comment: Let me put it this way.  Say you have a game with 20 levels, and each level has lots of different textures.  The user starts your game, surfaceCreated() is called only once, and your user wants to play your entire game in one sitting, without ever destroying your surface.  Are you going to load all 20 levels worth of textures at that moment?  Btw, hope you have a nice day too!

Comment: That is a reason, but not a permanent solution. All stuff that aren't level stuff should probably be loaded in `surfaceCreated()`. However, it all depends in which situation we're talking about, but the general initialization stuff should be done in `surfaceCreated()`, while, like you said, each level should probably be loaded in `drawFrame()`. :-)

Comment: I cannot load the Textures in surfaceCreated(), cause I dont know which Files I have to load at this time. On some point of runtime I get the information and then I need to load the image without the user taking notice of that.